# Output in Reverse in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I have a phrase that needs to be outputted in results.txt. The phrase comes from x.txt. For example: "I have two kids", it should output "kids two have I" in results.txt.

**UPDATE**

Its already working but i want no loop.
Pls see code below

**Code**

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p content=<x.txt
SET var=!content: =,!
SET rev=
:LOOP
IF NOT "!var!"=="" (
    FOR /F "delims=, tokens=1,*" %%F IN ("!var!") DO (
        SET rev=%%F,!rev!
        SET var=%%G
    )
) ELSE (
    SET rev=!rev:~0,-1!
    GOTO ENDLOOP
)
GOTO LOOP
:ENDLOOP
ECHO !rev:,= ! > results.txt
```

Comment: works fine - when I add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

Comment: What do you mean with "I want no loop"?

Comment: You don't want a loop, but what do you want instead? Recursion? A FOR-loop instead of a `GOTO` loop?

Comment: @jeb I dont want to loop in this case only. Although loop is recommended. I just wanted to try without any kind of loop

Comment: You want to process an unknown number of <n> elements without looping? You should patent that. Even recursion or *replacement magic* is a kind of looping

Comment: @jeb. Ok just make it a maximum of 4 words

Comment: `>result.txt (for /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in (x.txt) do echo %%d %%c %%b %%a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes the first four words (of each line) of the text file and rewrites them in reverse order to `result.txt`:

```
>result.txt (for /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in (x.txt) do echo %%d %%c %%b %%a)
```

Another solution (for a one-line text file, unspecified number of words):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo I have two little but wonderful kids>x.txt
<x.txt set /p x=
for %%a in (%x%) do set "res=%%a !res!"
>result.txt echo %res:~0,-1%
```

(although technically, the `for` command *is* a loop on its own)

Without any form of a loop, if you can live with some spaces at the front:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal 
echo I have two kids>x.txt
<x.txt set /p x=
call :reverse %x%
goto :eof
:reverse
set "rev=%9 %8 %7 %6 %5 %4 %3 %2 %1"
echo Reverse without any form of loop: "%rev%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%rev%") do echo To get rid of the spaces, you need a FOR loop: "%%a"
```

This is limited to a maximum of nine words because `cmd` supports only `%1`to `%9`
You can use more parameters (words) by using the `shift` command, but that would mean using a loop.

Comment: nice. but i dont wanna use any kind of loop

Comment: I can't imagine any reason to completely avoid any form of a loop (besides academic curiosity), but if you can live with some restrictions, it's possible. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three different ways.

1. Replacement magic (borrowed from Aacini)
2. For tokens
3. Recursion

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var=One two three four five"

call :rev1
call :rev2
call :rev3
exit /b


:rev1 -- replacement magic
setlocal
set "rev="
set rev=%var: = !rev!&Set rev=% !rev!

echo %0 !rev!
exit /b

:rev2 -- FOR toekns
setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=1-5" %%1 in ("%var%") do set "rev=%%5 %%4 %%3 %%2 %%1"
echo %0 !rev!
exit /b

:rev3 -- recursion
setlocal
set "rev="
call :__rev3_rec %var%
echo %0 !rev!
exit /b

:__rev3_rec
if "%1" == "" exit /b
call :__rev3_rec %2 %3 %4 %5
set "rev=%rev%%1 "
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question fully, so this is intended to reverse the order of each space separated substring per line.

For the task, I'd leverage PowerShell.

---

At the [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) prompt, *(powershell.exe)*:

```powershell
GC '.\x.txt'|%{$L=$_.Split(' ');[Array]::Reverse($L);$L -Join ' '}|SC '.\results.txt'
```

At the [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt), *(cmd.exe)*:

```cmd
"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoP "GC '.\x.txt'|%{$L=$_.Split(' ');[Array]::Reverse($L);$L -Join ' '}|SC '.\results.txt'
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoP "GC '.\x.txt'|%%{$L=$_.Split(' ');[Array]::Reverse($L);$L -Join ' '}|SC '.\results.txt'
```

---

If you're only working on the first line of the file, as opposed to all of them, a small modification is needed.

At the [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) prompt, *(powershell.exe)*:

```powershell
GC '.\x.txt' -To 1|%{$L=$_.Split(' ');[Array]::Reverse($L);$L -Join ' '}|SC '.\results.txt'
```

At the [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt), *(cmd.exe)*:

```cmd
"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoP "GC '.\x.txt' -To 1|%{$L=$_.Split(' ');[Array]::Reverse($L);$L -Join ' '}|SC '.\results.txt'
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoP "GC '.\x.txt' -To 1|%%{$L=$_.Split(' ');[Array]::Reverse($L);$L -Join ' '}|SC '.\results.txt'
```

---

Please note that, in both cases, if your strings are actually doublequoted, those will not move position. This means that `"I have two kids"`, would output as `kids" two have "I`, not `"kids two have I"`.